# Why is this line of Jquery selectiong ALL div's with the class=rule-name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a JQuery newb and trying to start out slow. I've put the following line of code into a Tampermonkey script and run it against the desired page.

```
$('<span id="matrixVarTableInit">Default Rule Tests</span>').insertAfter( "div:contains('Default Rule').rule-name" );
```

I would expect this to insert the HTML I provided (the span) after the div that contains the text 'Default Rule' and has class 'rule-name'.

However, instead this is inserting the HTML snippet after every div with class='rule-name' (effectively disregarding whether the tag has the text 'Default Rule' in it).

Comment: How is this off-topic???

Comment: _"How is this off-topic???"_ Because you have not reproduced the issue described at Question

Comment: Needing more info is different than being off-topic though. I will "reproduce the issue" when I get my kids to bed.

Comment: _"off-topic because... Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: For God's sake i'm dealing with two small children at the same time. I will get you your information when i get a chance. Please don't close this before I do so.

Comment: I think I see the issue here. The page I'm trying to inject my JS into is very JS-Heavy. The tag I'm trying to update is updated via Javascript when Clicking. I think my question is wrong given my scenario. Thank you for the help @guest271314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping position of `:contains()` and `.className` selectors

```
$('<span id="matrixVarTableInit">Default Rule Tests</span>')
.insertAfter("div.rule-name:contains('Default Rule')");
```

Comment: testing this now but the page isn't cooperating at the moment. Can you explain why the order matters? Is there some order of operations to consider?

Comment: Have not before tried chaining a string `.className` or other selector to jQuery `:contains()` selector. Not sure if that functionality is expected. You can try asking the question as to the expected functionality of a selector being chained to `:contains()` within parameter passed to a jQuery method at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues

Comment: This seems not to have worked. Each of the divs with "rule-name" as a class are getting the span inserted.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets or https://jsfiddle.net/psx48rn6/1 to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Note also 1) `id` of element in `document` should be unique; 2) you are appending an element to `document` which also contains text `"Default Rule"`

Comment: Evidently a selector can be chained to `:contains()` https://jsfiddle.net/psx48rn6/2/. That is not the issue. Though could be either 1) or 2) mentioned at previous comment

Comment: I will try to put together the jsfiddle to demonstrate a bit later. But I can tell you that there is no ID for the element I'm trying to target. I believe it is unique by text and classes.

Comment: Do you call the line at Question more than once? If you call the line more than once there would be elements having duplicate `id` `"matrixVarTableInit"` within `document`